# AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute '_meta' (when using South)

Tags: django

I'm getting this error when I use 'startmigration' in South.

My guess is that I have data that is not serializable.

What is the best way for me to determine the offending model?

Comment: Damn, my crystal ball is broken. Maybe you could post some code?

Comment: Daniel: I could post my entire models.py code but I don't think it would help. South was throwing just a very generic error and it doesn't say which line number the error is happening. My question is basically trying to figure out the process of determining if a model is serializable or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved this by removing the problematic field, applying the migration, adding the field again and doing another migration.

My problem was an inconsistency with a field name that I renamed and some previous migrations that were trying to find it. What would also probably work (and perhaps a better solution) is to edit the migration scripts in `<app>/migrations` to match the new field name.

I had to do this when updating the project in the production environment.

Comment: Maybe the first paragraph is not a good and "portable" solution. I had to modify the migration scripts to make the migration work anywhere in the production copies of the project.

Answer (score 0):

Since something is asking for `_meta` attribute, then it means, that it expects model (or form, to be preceise, but I believe it's not the case) object, since models have `_meta` attributes, but you are passing a string. If you more help, you need to present some code, to determine what is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Try updating to the latest version of South.  There have been some recent fixes for one cause of this.